# How i can solve the Forbidden (403) React.js framework?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, react-bootstrap

I am working with React.js framework on my project, all is well only when I try to update data, always seen Forbidden (403).

Comment: Please add more clarity, your question is too broad. Do you have your own backend API that is showing 403?

Comment: Hi! Do you want to be able to display an error message with React or do you want to solve your 403 in your backend? Please also rewrite your question if you're focusing on only one part.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its a problem with react.

##### According to MDN web docs :-

> 403 Forbidden
>
> The HTTP 403 Forbidden response status code indicates that the server understands the request but refuses to authorize it.
>
> This status is similar to [401](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401), but for the 403 Forbidden status code re-authenticating makes no difference. The access is permanently forbidden and tied to the application logic, such as insufficient rights to a resource.

**It means you don't have permission to that endpoint, maybe because of you are not added the credentials (password, jwt, token or something like that which authorize the request) to the request header in react front-end.**